# Flask Socket IO server not detecting changes

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

Changes made to the application.py file don't seem to be detected by the server after I save the file, even though debug mode is on. The only way I've been able to see changes is by exiting the server and restarting with `flask run`

Here is the code for application.py:

```
import os
import requests

from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    print('hello world')
    return 'hello!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

And here's the command line/terminal:

```
λ flask run
 * Serving Flask-SocketIO app "application.py"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 156-884-244
(3824) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(3824) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 50569)
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2018 20:07:40] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1536624459432-5 HTTP/1.1" 200 381 0.000000
(3824) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 50571)
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2018 20:07:40] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1536624460314-6&sid=79eb8e587f664e3383c946bb046717ca HTTP/1.1" 200 215 0.000000
(3824) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 50568)
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2018 20:07:44] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=79eb8e587f664e3383c946bb046717ca HTTP/1.1" 200 0 4.610168
hello world
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2018 20:07:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 0.000000
hello world
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2018 20:07:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 0.000000
hello world
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2018 20:08:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 0.000000
wsgi exiting
(3824) wsgi exited, is_accepting=True
```

Those `hello world`'s in command show up every time I change the text in `print('hello world')` and refresh the browser. Regardless of what I change it to, I always get the original version of the code's print argument.

Couple things I'm noticing:

- this issue doesn't occur when I'm just running Flask. When I'm just running Flask, I see in the command line/terminal that changes were detected.
- if I return a template of an HTML file, changes to the HTML file are automatically updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. It looks like the reloader does not work with you run the application via `flask run`. It does work, however, when you run it by running your application file (i.e. `python application.py`).

I'll log a bug and investigate.

Comment: Thanks Miguel! Yes, this does seem like a good workaround for now. Let me know what's causing issues with `flask run`

Comment: It should be fixed now, give it a try!